# Как отсортировать запрос с UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql

Имею такой MySQL запрос:

```
SELECT from_login, from_open_key, encrypt_by_from_key,
    who_login, who_open_key, encrypt_by_who_key, date_time
FROM Messages
WHERE from_login = '123' AND who_login='123456'

UNION

SELECT from_login, from_open_key, encrypt_by_from_key,
    who_login, who_open_key, encrypt_by_who_key, date_time
FROM Messages
WHERE from_login = '123456' AND who_login='123'
```

Как мне отсортировать результат этих двух запросов по полю date_time  чтобы первыми(сверху) были самые новый а снизу самые старые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавить в конец запроса:

- новые в начале - `order by date_time desc`
- старые в начале - `order by date_time asc`

Comment: Desc, вероятно, судя по вопросу.

Comment: тьфу, да. дополню. я чего-т об алфавитном порядке задумался

Answer (score 1):

```
order by date_time asc
```

Кто-то ответил, но сразу же удалил ответ. Не успел посмотреть, кто именно это был но знай что твой ответ помог. Спасибо))

Comment: эт я был, думал Уколов даст развернутый ответ, он так хорошо отформатировал сообщение твое, кстати, форматируй их, пожалуйста, перед отправкой. в MySQL Workbench можно автоматически это делать (ctrl+b)